# Trouble installing ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I tried to install the latest version, I think it was 13.4. Now I'm trying the previous version.

It crashes every time. Not really error messages as much as it will freeze or crash during installation. Today it did something different, it crashed and went to a black screen with white letters. I tried to take a picture but it went away too quickly.

Is is possible it is not compatible with my hardware?

Comment: What error messages are you getting if any?  How are you installing? Which Ubuntu release are you installing?

Comment: I tried 13.4 I think it was, the latest version. Now I'm trying the previous version. Not really error messages as much as it will freeze or crash during installation. Today it did something different, it crashed and went to a black screen with white letters. I tried to take a picture but it went away too quickly.

Comment: Probably not. Could you share your PC specs?

Comment: What is your exact hardware specs?

Comment: Just wanted to let every one know after about a week of jacking with it as soon as I posted it installed. Thank you all for such prompt responses

Answer (score 1):

This is also a shot in the dark, but consider downloading from a different mirror site, checking the checksum of the file, and burning to a new dvd/cd at a slower rate.

Also, never neglect to check your actual hardware ex. http://www.memtest86.com/